# auth0 cannot read poperty options of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I try to get auth0 running on a simple react app.

I create a auth0 object with the folling parameter:

```
this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
        clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
        redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.redirectUri,
        audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
        responseType: AUTH_CONFIG.responseType,
        scope: AUTH_CONFIG.scope,
    });
```

after I logg in on the Auth0 website and get redirected to my callback url I get the error

> cannot read poperty of undefined

I just cant figer out where this error located.

In my Applcation in auth0 i configured: Allowed Callback URLs: *http://localhost:3000/callback*

Comment: There might be few other places like CORS one where you need to configure it: Check here: https://github.com/nuxt/example-auth0.  Can you invoke manually  the /callback url? Do you have such route supported on your webserver?

Comment: hm, Im doing a SPA and i put allow lochalhost in every option field in auth0 …^^ 

my SPA knows a route with **/callback**

Comment: Are you sure you have the route on the backend /webserver . SPA front end route won't work in this case.